# SQL Server 2008R2, EXEC() AT LinkedServer, IBM DB2. Error: Authentication Failed,

Tags: sql-server, authentication, stored-procedures, db2

I am having a problem using an web application against a stored procedure. I have a stored procedure that uses

```
EXEC('Query') AT LinkedServerName
```

My application uses a service account as the identity in the application pool. When I run the stored procedure from my application I receive this error message

```
The OLE DB provider \"MSDASQL\" for linked server \"E04\" reported an error. Authentication failed
```

I tried putting in `EXECUTE AS LOGIN MyLogin`, but it still fails even though sql server profiler shows that MyLogin is running the stored procedure after the custom account for my application logs in. I am guessing the `EXECUTE AS LOGIN` does not cascade down to the `EXEC() AT`.

Is  the only option to change the permissions on the linked server? Is the service account from my application not using the remote username and password defined in the properties of the linked server?

Comment: You have the name of the user in the error message ("User" does not have the authority to perform the requested command or operation.) -- which user is it?

Comment: sorry, the user is the application pool identity I am using

Comment: no sorry I botched the error when I wrote it here. I did some more research and the error in my application is simpler. The error I received when I tried to test it in SQL Server was giving me false results I believe. I updated the question